# option value with in_array not working

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu

I have

```
$this->getcoursebyid[0]['p_id']=2,4
```

**$this->getprofile**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [profile_id] => 1
                [profile_name] => Administrator
                [profile_type] => GLOBAL
                [profile_tag] => ADM
                [profile_default] => 0
            )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [profile_id] => 2
            [profile_name] => Product Owner
            [profile_type] => GLOBAL
            [profile_tag] => PO
            [profile_default] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [profile_id] => 3
            [profile_name] => Team member
            [profile_type] => GLOBAL
            [profile_tag] => MEMBER
            [profile_default] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [profile_id] => 4
            [profile_name] => Tester
            [profile_type] => GLOBAL
            [profile_tag] => TES
            [profile_default] => 0
        )

)
```

I want to select `$this->getcoursebyid[0]['p_id']` from option value so i did the following

```
$proid=explode(',',$this->getcoursebyid[0]['p_id']);

<select name="framework[]" multiple id="framework" class="form-control" >
    <?php
      $i=0;
       foreach ($this->getprofile as $getprofile):                                                       
    ?>                         
    <option value="<?php echo $getprofile['profile_id'] ?>"<?php if(in_array($proid[$i],$getprofile)){ ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>><?php echo $getprofile['profile_name'] ?>_<?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
  </select>
```

But this is not working..i didn't get proper values .Any help would be appreciated

Comment: **`I want to select 2,4 from option value so i did the following`** can you please elaborate.

Comment: @MayurShedage i have update my question..sorry for my bad english

Comment: As `$proid` only consist of two values `(i.e array(0=>2,1=>4))`, it gives an error on third iteration of the loop when `$i=2` so it would be like `$proid[2]` - doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating $this->getprofile and assigning its index in $proid[$i], but $proid is having only two indexes array(0=>2,1=>4) So it will obviously give you error.

```
<select name="framework[]" multiple id="framework" class="form-control" >
 <?php
   $i=0;
   foreach ($this->getprofile as $getprofile):
   ?>                         
   <option value="<?php echo $getprofile['profile_id'] ?>"<?php if(in_array($proid[$i],$getprofile)){ ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>><?php echo $getprofile['profile_name'] ?>_<?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
   </select>
```

You should read in_array manual

```
in_array(needle, haystack)
```

Below is the solution.

```
<select name="framework[]" multiple id="framework" class="form-control" >
 <?php
   $i=0;
   foreach ($this->getprofile as $getprofile):
  ?>                         
   <option value="<?php echo $getprofile['profile_id'] ?>"<?php if(in_array($getprofile['profile_id'],$proid)){ ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>><?php echo $getprofile['profile_name'] ?>_<?php echo $i; ?></option>
   <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>

                                    </select>
```

Comment: Happy Coding :)